# SQL if column1 matches column2 add 1 to column3

Tags: sql, if-statement, indexing, compare

I am currently working on SQL.

If the data in column1 matches column2 then 1 should be added an index in column3.

E.G.

1. column1     column2
2. B7          A8
3. A8          Q9
4. L1          X2

So It must search through both columns and add 1 to a third column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET column3 = COALESCE(column3, 0) + 1
    WHERE column1 = column2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just run a query, it would be something like the following:

```
SELECT column1, column2, CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END column3 FROM tbl
```

If you are trying to actually update the table then you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET column3 = CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```